# std::rotate arguments not correct?

Tags: c++, vector, rotation, iterator, unordered-map

I have a vector containing iterators for an `unordered_map` and I want to use `std::rotate` on the iterators, but I must be missing something.

The code works when I do someting like

```
std::vector<std::unordered_map<int, int>::iterator> _lruList;

void used(std::unordered_map<int, int>::iterator& it, int type) {
    if (type == 0) {
        auto item = _lruList.begin();
        while (item != _lruList.end()){
            if (*item == it){
                std::rotate(item, item + 1, _lruList.end());
                return;
            }
            item++;
        }
    }
}
```

but I want the code to work like this, because this function is called a lot, in which the extra while loop adds extra unneccessary time complexity

```
std::vector<std::unordered_map<int, int>::iterator> _lruList;
    void used(std::unordered_map<int, int>::iterator& it, int type) {
        if (type == 0) {
            std::rotate(it, it + 1, _lruList.end()); //error on it
            return;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Some more code, I see that the types of it and _lruList.end() conflicts. Is there anyway that I can fix this to still accomplish that I want to do without iterating through the vector?

After further debugging, it appears that `it + 1` is giving me an `"error type"` according to VS2015.

```
std::unordered_map<int, int>::iterator found = _cache.find(key);
// if key doesn't exist, return -1
if (found == _cache.end()) {
    return -1;
}
// if key exists, return value and update lru
used(found, 0);
return found->second;
```

I can provide more code snippets if that would help answer my question.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *"in which the extra while loop adds extra unneccessary time complexity"* -- Why do you think it's unnecessary?

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley Well because I think this is the part where my code times out. This is a problem on LeetCode called LRU Cache, in which there is a time limit, in which my code time exceeds on. So I'm just trying to figure out ways to reduce time complexity without changing my data structures first. I guess "unnecessary" is a bad way to put it

Answer (score 2):

```
void used(std::unordered_map<int, int>::iterator& it, int type) {
    if (type == 0) {
        std::rotate(it, it + 1, _lruList.end()); //error on it
        return;
    }
}
```

In this function, `it` (and `it + 1`) is of type

```
std::unordered_map<int, int>::iterator
```

But `_lruList.end()` is of of a completely different type

```
std::vector<std::unordered_map<int, int>::iterator>::iterator
```

All three of the arguments to `std::rotate` need to be of the same type (as well as from the same container). So I don't know what you're trying to do, but this call obviously cannot work:

```
std::rotate(it, it + 1, _lruList.end());
```

Comment: Ah, I see.
Here's what I'm trying to do
`std::unordered_map<int, int>::iterator found = _cache.find(key);
used(found, 0);`